# Trace who and when a site collection got deleted Permanently in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, site, collection

A site collection was missing, nothing in the recycle bin. `Get-SPDeletedSite` return nothing. Are there any log that i can trace who and when the site collection got deleted?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no easy way to find who deleted the site collection, once it gone from every where. But still you can try couple of things, may be you get some clue.

**Option 1**

- check the IIS logs on the WFE and try to find the `/_layouts/deleteweb.aspx`(if deleted from the site collection itself) or  `/_admin/delsite.aspx`(if site collection deleted from Central Admin).

**Option 2**

- check the event cache table on the content Database and try to search the site collection name.

Lastly, you should check the ULS logs on all sharepoint server and see if you find short url of site collection.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to find out the user who deleted Site collection.
However you can use **Get-SPDeletedSite -ContentDatabase "WSS_CONTENT"** to obtain a deleted site collection reference object.

It returns object that contain information about deletion time, but not about user who deleted Site.

Follow this link for more information

http://www.dynamics101.com/2014/02/restore-deleted-site-collection-sharepoint/